# how to access a text file from USB of a client machine from an ASP.NET Website

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, activex

Hii I am trying to implement an additional security option other than just password.  To log in the client must insert pen drive which contains a text file with a key provided by us. And in order to do that i need to  locate the file and read the file. IS there any method to access the file using C# code or Java script. Or Do i have to use active X Control Can any one just a good method to do this ......

Comment: You have to use a _signed_ activex control or a _signed_ java applet (not javascript) to get out of the browser sandbox and access the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way of doing this, and it's not even a very good security mechanism -- if one site can read the file from your pen drive, then another site would be likely to be able to do the same thing, stealing the contents of the secret file and breaking your security.

A far better approach would likely be to implement a [time-based one-time-password (TOTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) scheme, similar to what Google and various other sites do.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I was trying to convince the same thing to my senior This message made an impact in his decision

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5 file read api and then send the text to the server for verification.
Here is a [Tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)